# Java Solicitando Datos a Usuario y Guardarlos en Excel

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Buena noche tengo el siguiente codigo el cual quiero ir guardando mas datos en un archivo de excel ya que el primer dato se guarda correctamente en la primera celda.

El inconveniente es que unicamente va guardando en la primer celda y no utiliza mas celdas de la primera columna. Ayuda Porfavor (soy nuevo en java y es mi primer Lenguaje de Programacion que estoy empezando estudiar). se los agradecere mucho.

```
public void crear(){
    HSSFWorkbook libro = new HSSFWorkbook();// Se crea el libro
    HSSFSheet hoja = libro.createSheet();// Se crea una hoja dentro del libro
    HSSFRow fila = hoja.createRow(0);// Se crea una fila dentro de la hoja
    HSSFCell celda = fila.createCell((short) 0);// Se crea una celda dentro de la fila

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);//Scanner entrada de datos

    String nombre;
    System.out.println("Ingrese los nombres");
    nombre = in.nextLine();

    HSSFRichTextString texto = new HSSFRichTextString(nombre);// Se crea el contenido de la celda y se mete en ella.
    celda.setCellValue(texto);

    // Se salva el libro.
    try {
        FileOutputStream elFichero = new FileOutputStream("holamundo.xls");
        libro.write(elFichero);
        elFichero.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tu problema principal es no contar con un mecanismo que solicite o cree las celdas de forma dinámica ya que con ese código siempre se pisara la fila y celda 0.

Te paso un Ejemplo de como crear una cabecera y un detalle mediante un for.

```
public void crear(){
HSSFWorkbook libro = new HSSFWorkbook();// Se crea el libro
HSSFSheet hoja = libro.createSheet();// Se crea una hoja dentro del libro
//se crea una sola Hoja una sola vez.

//se crear fila y celda cabecera y/o nombre columna.
HSSFRow fila = hoja.createRow(0);// Se crea una fila dentro de la hoja
HSSFCell celda = fila.createCell((short) 0);// Se crea una celda dentro de la fila
celda.setCellValue("NOMBRES");

//se crear un for para simular 10 filas y celdas.

for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    HSSFRow fila1 = hoja.createRow(i);// Se crea una fila dentro de la hoja
    HSSFCell celda1 = fila1.createCell((short) 0);// para nuestro ejemplo la celda siempre es cero.

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);//Scanner entrada de datos
    String nombre;
    System.out.println("Ingrese los nombres");
    nombre = in.nextLine();

    HSSFRichTextString texto = new HSSFRichTextString(nombre);// Se crea el contenido de la celda y se mete en ella.
    celda1.setCellValue(texto);
}

// Se salva el libro.
try {
    //archivo
    FileOutputStream elFichero = new FileOutputStream("holamundo.xls");
    libro.write(elFichero);//escribe en la hoja.
    elFichero.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

}
```

Esto Solicitara al usuario ingresar 10 nombres llenando así 10 celdas.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: muchas gracias, muy claro el ejemplo.
pero mi duda principal es que quiero ingresar datos pero sin necesidad de tener un limite.
ejemplo: ingreso un nombre, se llena una celda y cierro mi programa, luego ejecuto el programa y me vuelve a pedir que ingrese un nombre y el segundo nombre ingresado lo va guardando y asi sucesivamente, sin necesidad que me pida la cantidad de nombres a ingresar.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno en el caso de que quieras que siempre el nombre ingresado se vaya al final cada vez que ejecutes, deberias modificar el archivo y no adicionarlo.

Hice un ejemplo rápido pero funcional en el caso de que te sirva te pediria que lo optimises, espero te sea de ayuda.

Aqui va el ejemplo:

```
String pathFile = "holamundo.xls";
try{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);//Scanner entrada de datos
    System.out.println("Ingrese un nombre");
    String nombre = in.nextLine();

    FileOutputStream fileOut;
    File fileXls = new File(pathFile);
    if (!fileXls.isFile()) { // Si el archivo no existe se crea
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(pathFile);
        HSSFWorkbook book = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = book.createSheet("Lista de nombres");
        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0); // Asignamos el indice de la fila
        HSSFCell celdasReg = row.createCell(0); // Asignamos el indice de la columna
        celdasReg.setCellValue(nombre);
        book.write(fileOut);
    }
    else { // Si el archivo existe solo se modifica
        InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(pathFile); 
        Workbook book = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        Sheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(0); 
        Row row = sheet.getRow(0); 
        Cell cell = row.getCell(0); 
        String cellContents = cell.getStringCellValue(); 

        // Agregamos un nuevo row con el nuevo nombre
        int rows = sheet.getLastRowNum(); // Aqui recuperamos la ultima fila ingresada
        Row rowNew = sheet.createRow(rows + 1); // Asignamos el indice de la fila
        Cell cellNew = rowNew.createCell(0); // Asignamos la columna
        cellNew.setCellValue(nombre);

        cell.setCellValue(cellContents);
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(pathFile);
        book.write(fileOut);
    }
    fileOut.close();
}
catch(IOException ex){
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
} catch (InvalidFormatException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Posiblemente necesitas de la libreria [poi-ooxml](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpoiooxml39jar.htm), esa es la version que yo utilice para el ejemplo, esto sobretodo para poder utilizar WorkbookFactory.